# Lambda POST Request to AWS API Gateway

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

I have an AWS API Gateway that uses lambda functions in Node.js to work with a PostgreSQL RDS. After having successfully managed to pass GET requests through my gateway, I’m now trying to work out how to send POST requests and insert data into my database.

I reused the code from my GET request and made some changes along the way, using the notes I took from other articles and stack posts I came across while I was learning about the concept. My lambda code is as follows:

```
console.log('PostgreSQL POST Function');

var pg = require("pg");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var conn = "postgres://URL";
    var client = new pg.Client(conn);
    client.connect();

    //var id = event.id;
    var userid = event.userid;
    var username = event.username;
    var userpwd = event.userpwd;
    var userfirstname = event.userfirstname;
    var userlastname = event.userlastname;
    var usercontactnbr = event.usercontactnbr;

    console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database’);

    //var query = client.query(`INSERT INTO users(userid, username, userpwd, userfirstname, userlastname, usercontactnbr) VALUES ('${userid}’, '${username}', '${userpwd}', '${userfirstname}', '${userlastname}', '${usercontactnbr}');`);
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        console.log(jsonString);
        client.end();
        context.succeed(jsonObj);
    });
};
```

I then went on to set the content type of my mapping templates in my gateway to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set the termplate as:

```
{
    "userid": "$input.json('userid')",
    "username": "$input.json('username')",
    "userpwd": "$input.json('userpwd')",
    "userfirstname": "$input.json('userfirstname')",
    "userlastname": "$input.json('userlastname')",
    "usercontactnbr": "$input.json('usercontactnbr')"
}
```

When I ran the the request in POSTMAN with a sample request body that looks like:

```
{
    "userid": 1,
    "username": "Q",
    "userpwd": "q",
    "userfirstname": "q",
    "userlastname": "q",
    "usercontactnbr": "1"
}
```

I came upon status 200 OK message but with an error saying:

> 2020-10-02T19:58:34.126Z   ………     ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"body is not defined","stack":["ReferenceError: body is not defined","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:36:17)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)”]}

So I went on to change the template to the following:

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

But now I get a status 415 Unsupported media type error.

Where am I going wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: the format you are submitted is not "application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and is "application/json"... your integration should probably expect that type.  Also, are you setting your content type header in your request to match the expectations of the api gateway? 415 usually means that it's getting a content-type header that is either missing or does not match one you have provided

Comment: Oh I think I missed out the content type header. I did mention it in the mapping template, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: are you adding the content-type header in POSTMAN?

Comment: Yes, but every time I set the content-type header to ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` I still see ```application/json``` in it. And now I’m getting a 400 Bad gateway error stating: ```{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'\"\' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{\n    \"username\": \"\"\"\",\n    \"userpwd\": \"\"\"\",\n    \"userfirstname\": \"\"\"\",\n    \"userlastname\": \"\"\"\",\n    \"usercontactnbr\": \"\"\"\"\n}\"; line: 2, column: 20]”}```